# How can I do findBy operations with attributes not directly on the entity hibernate spring JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have three entities with the following relationship
Entity User has many Activities (Unidirectional relationship) with join table because I need relationship attributes,
Rule entity has many activities (bidirectional relationship)

Can I do a findBy that search Activities that are from one specific rule?
it sounds possible because Activities has rule but I don't know how to do this with Hibernate

This is my code from both relationships

EDIT: I've tested with MySQL and the query that I need is this

```
select * from user_activity where user_id = userIdValue and activity_id in (
select id from activity where rule_id = rule_idValue);
```

how can I do that query with hibernate on spring?

User-Activity (With join table for relationship attributes)

```
@Entity
@Table(name="USER_ACTIVITY")
public class JoinedUserActivity {

public JoinedUserActivity() {}

public JoinedUserActivity(JoinedUserActivityId joinedUserActivityId, String fileName) {
    this.joinedUserActivityId = joinedUserActivityId;
    this.fileName  = fileName;
    this.score = 0;
    this.lastHint = 0;
}
private String fileName; //user activity filename
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="ACTIVITY_ID", insertable=false, updatable=false)
private Activity activity;


private Integer score;
private Integer lastHint; 

public Activity getActivity() {
    return activity;
}

public void setActivity(Activity activity) {
    this.activity = activity;
}
//more set and gets
@EmbeddedId
private JoinedUserActivityId joinedUserActivityId;


// required because JoinedUserAchievments contains composite id
@Embeddable
public static class JoinedUserActivityId implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -9180674903145773104L;


    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="USER_ID")
    private User user;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="ACTIVITY_ID")
    private Activity activity;

    // required no arg constructor
    public JoinedUserActivityId() {}

    public JoinedUserActivityId(User user, Activity activity) {
        this.user = user;
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    public JoinedUserActivityId(Integer userId, Integer activityId) {
        this(new User(userId), new Activity(activityId));
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }


    public Activity getActivity() {
        return activity;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public void setActivity(Activity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
    }
    @Override

    public boolean equals(Object instance) {
        if (instance == null)
            return false;

        if (!(instance instanceof JoinedUserActivityId))
            return false;

        final JoinedUserActivityId other = (JoinedUserActivityId) instance;
        if (!(user.getId().equals(other.getUser().getId())))
            return false;

        if (!(activity.getId().equals(other.getActivity().getId())))
            return false;

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 7;
        hash = 47 * hash + (this.user != null ? this.user.hashCode() : 0);
        hash = 47 * hash + (this.activity != null ? this.activity.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }
  }
}
```

User

```
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="joinedUserActivityId.user")
private List<JoinedUserActivity> joinedUserActivityList = new ArrayList<JoinedUserActivity>();
```

Activity has no info about User because is unidirectional.

Now my Activity-rule has no join table and bidirectional with the following code
Activity.java

```
@JsonIgnore
@ManyToOne
Rule rule;
```

Rule.java

```
 @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="rule")
 private List<Activity> ListActivities = new ArrayList<Activity>();
```

so... on join table user_activity, can  I define a findBy function that returns which activities has one user from one rule?

I've managed to do

```
@Override
JoinedUserActivity findOne(JoinedUserActivityId id);
```

this returns one Activity from one user
but I don't know how to filter by Rule

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You subquery isn't needed. All you need is a join.

In JPQL:

```
select distinct jua from JoinedUserActivity jua
where jua.user.id = :userId
and jua.activity.rule.id = :ruleId
```

Or, using explicit joins:

```
select distinct jua from JoinedUserActivity jua
join jua.user u
join jua.activity a
join a.rule r
where u.id = :userId
and r.id = :ruleId
```

Now just add the method you want in your Spring-data repositoty interface, and annotated it with `@Query`, with one of the above queries as value.

Comment: I had to change jua.user.id to jua.joinedUserActivityId.user.id  and this worked for me, thanks!